# Pause jQuery on click of button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, onclick

I have some jQuery that is applying some CSS transitions to a div on a loop. See [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jFIT/86KLb/7/) They work along side a slideshow so I've managed to get them in sync with each other.

I wondered if there is a way that on click of a separate button these jQuery commands could pause and on second click would resume what they were doing from the position they were at when they stopped?

```
doIt();

function doIt(){
$('.title1').fadeIn('fast', function() {
$('div').addClass('animated pulse');
})
$('div').one('webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend    
animationend', function() {
$('.title1').fadeOut(2000, function() {doIt();});
});
};
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

[jquery's .stop()](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) may be what you need, but beware of this:

> "If more than one animation method is called on the same element, the later animations are placed in the effects queue for the element. These animations will not begin until the first one completes. When .stop() is called, the next animation in the queue begins immediately."

To resume, you'll have to reapply the effect, usually (e.g. your fadeIn, which will carry on fading in from wherever it has got to).

Answer (score 0):

What you can do here is ,u can unbind the events on that div, Which will Sop the animation

```
   $('#btn').bind("click",function(e){

     $('div').unbind(); //Unbind Fadein,Fadeout events only if u have other events on this div
     $('.title1').unbind();

});
```

button HTML

```
<input type="button" id="btn" value="Stop this"></input>
```

Fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/86KLb/14/

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer - how would I do it if I wanted a pause and a separate play button?